# Вывод адреса метода класса. Различия в выводе с помощью printf() и cout

Tags: c++

Добрый день. Объясните пожалуйста, почему когда я пытаюсь вывести адрес метода класса с помощью функции printf(), он выводится в консоль в обычном 16-ном виде, но когда использую для этой цели cout, выводится 1. Почему так происходит? В интернете ничего не нашел, возможно плохо искал. Что значит 1? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
PhoneBook book("Rafalsky", "Andrey", "Anatoliyovich", 13, 2, 1999, "+380999999999", "Uk", "Polt");
    printf("Person::Show -- %p\n", &Person::Show);
    cout << &Person::Show << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Функция `printf` с параметром `p` не может вывести значение указателя на метод класса, так как указатель на метод класса не может быть приведен к `void *`. `cout` же приводит указатель на метод класса к `bool`. Никаких встроенных методов для печати значений указателей на методы класса нет. Можно попробовать выводить значение указателя побайтово:

```
auto p_method{&Person::Show};
auto p_byte{reinterpret_cast<::std::uint8_t const *>(::std::addressof(p_method))};
::std::size_t byte_index{};
do
{
    ::std::cout << ::std::hex << ::std::setw(2) << ::std::setfill('0') <<
        static_cast<::std::uint32_t>(p_byte[byte_index]);
    ++byte_index;
}
while(sizeof(p_method) != byte_index);
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KqksiAlE04BD2DNe)

Comment: можно было и попроще